# Why doesn't Visual Studio open my projects after an upgrade to the latest version?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

```
Overview
    Project Path    Errors  Warnings    Messages
    Fractal10   Fractal10\Fractal10.fsproj  1   0   0
    Solution    Fractal10.sln   0   0   1
Solution and projects
```

I upgraded Visual F# to this version:

```
fsharp - Visual F# Tools 15.4.1.17081601
```

on this webpage: https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/fsharp/package/vsix/VisualFSharp

and now my projects do not open. See the message below. The link on the message does not have any useful information. Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

```
Fractal10
    Message
    Fractal10\Fractal10.fsproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=660342&projecttype=F2A71F9B-5D33-465A-A702-920D77279786
Solution
    Message
    Fractal10.sln: The solution file does not require migration.
    Hide 1 additional messages
```

Comment: I know two things you can try: 1) Make sure F# support is selected in the VS installer. Apparently it got deselected for some users. 2) Install Visual Studio 2017 Update 3. That was the only thing that fixed it for me.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev - Thanks. It worked. Just for the record here is what I did. 1) Started VS Installer. 2) It said I needed to upgrade, so I did it. 3) After VS Installer was upgraded I installed the new VS Studio.

Comment: @Soldalma btw https://twitter.com/_cartermp/status/898603268615491584